# clear an efficient Adapter at runtime in android

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to clear a list view with efficient adapter in android. How will I achieve this? Pease help me out.

Comment: How "efficient" does it need to be? There are several ListAdapter sub-classes... can you give more information on what your requirements are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeh definitely,

you are using an Array in order to fill the Efficient adapter, make that array size to 0,

it automatically serves your purpose.

If you find it useful, Dont forget to mark it as an answer